# Why Can't I Use std.algorithm.count With a Predicate Function

Tags: d, phobos

The following code fails to compile:

```
assert("(((())))()()()()))".count!(c => c.among!('(', ')')) > 0);
```

With the error message:

```
"Error: template std.algorithm.searching.count cannot deduce function from argument types !((c) => c.among!('(', ')'))(string), candidates are..."
```

But the [standard library (http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_searching.html#.count) clearly shows that there is an overload of `count` that takes a predicate, counting all element of `R` for which the predicate returns true. So why does the compiler complain when I try to use `count` this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`assert("(((())))()()()()))".count!(c => c.among!('(', ')') != 0) > 0);`

The problems are:

1. That your lambda is returning `uint` instead of `bool` (check the documentation for the return value of `among`).
2. That the compiler error is not helpful.

Comment: That's odd, the template constraint specifically says `is(typeof(unaryFun!pred(haystack.front)) : bool)`. I would've thought that `is(uint: bool)` would return true, but I guess not.